# Error while opening Outlook email message in [ScriptableMember] in silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I am trying to call a Silver Light method from Javascript.
Registerred a method, and trying to open a new outlook email message.

But I am getting this error:

`Error: System.NotSupportedException: This operation is not supported in the current context.
   at System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObjectInfo.Invoke(ManagedObject obj, InvokeType invokeType, String memberName, ScriptParam[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.ManagedHost.InvokeScriptableMember(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nMemberID, Int32 nInvokeType, Int32 nArgCount, ScriptParam[] pArgs, ScriptParam& pResult, ExceptionInfo& pExcepInfo)`

- I have configured silver light project to run out of browser with elevated rights

this is the code i a using in the method:

```
 var olMail = outlook.CreateItem(0);
            //olMail.To = txtTO.Text;
            //olMail.Cc = txtCC.Text;
            olMail.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\temp\\Test_pdf.pdf");
            olMail.Subject = "Subject of email.";
            olMail.HTMLBody = "This is first email.";
            olMail.Display();
            //olMail.Save();
            //You can send a mail by using Send() method.
            //olMail.Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

When Silverlight is running out of browser it has no html host page.  Microsoft states: functions under System.Windows.Browser namespace can't be used in OOB mode.

***EDIT***

I grabbed the example from the link you posted and did the following to make it run:

1. Installed the app - this will not work when running in browser.
2. Commented out the line: //olMail.Attachments.Add(@"C:\SMOExample.bak");

Comment: Thanks but I am very confused that why ppl are writing articles: **http://www.devcurry.com/2011/05/silverlight-4-and-com-sending-mails.html** stating that it is possible?